# resample a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a `DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex`.  The first level is a `DatetimeIndex` with weekly frequency.  The second level is **NOT** consistent across groupings by the first level.

I want to group the first level by month and take the first weeks rows.

### Setup

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='W', periods=10).repeat(2),
    list('ABCDEFGHIJ' * 2)
], names=['Date', 'Thing'])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Col=np.arange(10, 30)), midx)
```

---

### Expected Results

```
df

                  Col    
Date       Thing     
2018-01-07 A       10    # This is the first week
           B       11    # of January 2018 
2018-01-14 C       12
           D       13
2018-01-21 E       14
           F       15
2018-01-28 G       16
           H       17
2018-02-04 I       18    # This is the first week
           J       19    # of February 2018
2018-02-11 A       20
           B       21
2018-02-18 C       22
           D       23
2018-02-25 E       24
           F       25
2018-03-04 G       26    # This is the first week
           H       27    # of March 2018
2018-03-11 I       28
           J       29
```

Results should be

```
                  Col    
Date       Thing     
2018-01-07 A       10    # This is the first week
           B       11    # of January 2018 
2018-02-04 I       18    # This is the first week
           J       19    # of February 2018
2018-03-04 G       26    # This is the first week
           H       27    # of March 2018
```

---

### Attempt

```
df.unstack().asfreq('M', 'ffill').stack()

                   Col
Date       Thing      
2018-01-31 G      16.0
           H      17.0
2018-02-28 E      24.0
           F      25.0
```

This is wrong on several levels.

1. Date is actual month end and not the actual date observed.
2. Things are not from the correct date.  Notice that I wanted `['A', 'B']` from `'2018-01-07'` and not `['G', 'H']`.
3. I'm unstacking to enable myself to use `asfreq` but that introduces `nan` and converts to `float`
4. I don't know what happened to `March 2018`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
In [384]: date = df.index.get_level_values('Date')

In [385]: firstweek = date.to_frame().groupby(date.strftime('%Y-%m')).min()['Date']

In [386]: df[date.isin(firstweek)]
Out[386]:
                  Col
Date       Thing
2018-01-07 A       10
           B       11
2018-02-04 I       18
           J       19
2018-03-04 G       26
           H       27
```

---

Details

```
In [387]: date.to_frame().groupby(date.strftime('%Y-%m')).min()
Out[387]:
              Date
2018-01 2018-01-07
2018-02 2018-02-04
2018-03 2018-03-04
```

---

Alternative.

```
In [400]: fweek = df.assign(dt=date).resample('M', level='Date')['dt'].min()

In [401]: df[date.isin(fweek)]
Out[401]:
                  Col
Date       Thing
2018-01-07 A       10
           B       11
2018-02-04 I       18
           J       19
2018-03-04 G       26
           H       27
```

Comment: I like it a lot!

Comment: I had another solution but this led to `df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series().resample('M').first()]` which is much nicer.

Comment: Ah, that's nice one.

Answer (score 1):

If first week of the month is just the first seven days of the month, you could just filter like this

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0).day <= 7]

                Col
Date       Thing     
2018-01-07 A       10
           B       11
2018-02-04 I       18
           J       19
2018-03-04 G       26
           H       27
```

Unless your looking for the first week ending on a Sunday, in that case this wouldn't work.

Comment: Clever, but easily broken.